# Bind component on observable boxed primitive value

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

What I want?

I want a mobx-react component to be binded on boxed observable primitive value from state. So I expect component to rerender if value changes.

Using lodash,

```
type BusinessData = { root: { path: { value: string } };

@observable state = buildInitialState();

const buildInitialState = () : BusinessData => {root: {}};

<BindedComponent value = {_.get(state, 'root.path.value')} />

const fetchState = () : BusinessData => { root: { path: { value: 'potato' } } };
```

What is the problem?

At the moment of first application rendering `root.path` is `undefined`. It will be fetched later on some stage of some internal component lifecycle or on user action. Furthermore, it might even not be fetched from server. Such path might not exist in data until user edits some input and this value will be set.

Supposable solution - initialize whole state explicitly:

```
const buildInitialState = () : BusinessData => { root: { path: { value:  undefined } } };
```

Then `BindedComponent` can bind on boxed `undefined` and observe changes. This is bad, because when state is deep nested, I have to write such a boilerplate. And also in my case shape of business data can have a lof of implementations. So I have to initialize explicitly every one of them in all my projects.

Any ideas on how I can solve this without boilerplate?

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep your state structure simple:

```
@observable state = { root: { path: { value: null } }
```

You can then create a simple update function:

```
async setStateValue(value) {
      try {
       this.state.root.path.value = await value
      } catch (e) {
       console.log(e)
   }
}
```

Calling this at the rendering stage, will automatically update your component once the promise has been completed:

```
async updateFromComponent() {
      await setStateValue('potato')
 }

const {value} = prop.store.state.root.path
render (){
    return (
    <BindedComponent value = {value} />
)
}
```